# Reading multiple opened files using readlines() results in empty array

Tags: python, file, readlines

I have 2 files that I want to manipulate. One of the files (`in.txt`) is opened in read mode, `'r'`, the other (`out.txt`) is in append mode and should be able to be read from as well, `'a+'`.

As an example let's suppose the contents of the `in.txt` file is:

```
Foo
```

And the contents of the `out.txt` file is:

```
Bar
```

If I run this script on the same folder the files are stored at, *(please, pay no attention to variable names, this is just to simplify the example...I hope)*:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as i, open('out.txt', 'a+') as o:
    in_data = i.readlines()
    out_data = o.readlines()
    
    print(in_data)
    print(out_data)
```

This is the output:

```
['Foo\n']
[]
```

The contents of the `output file` will not be read into the array.

How should I proceed to be able to use both files as expected? Is this related to the file pointer of the open operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with opening multiple files.

When you open a file in append mode, you're initially positioned at the end of the file, so there's nothing to read. You need to seek to the beginning to read the contents.

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as i, open('out.txt', 'a+') as o:
    in_data = i.readlines()
    o.seek(0)
    out_data = o.readlines()
    
    print(in_data)
    print(out_data)
```

Comment: I see, I was wrongly assuming it was something related to the previous readlines(). 
Should I also seek to the bottom of the file for write operations after reading the contents?

Comment: When opening in append mode, it automatically seeks to the end whenever you write. That's the difference between write and append.

Comment: Thank you once again for the replies. I will accept the answer as soon as the cooldown ends. Cheers.